# run script on logout

Tags: linux, debian

I have the following bash script on debian with the LSB header:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: shutdown_vms
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop: gdm vmware $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:
# Default-Stop: 0 2 3 4 5 6
# Short-Description: Shutdown vms
# Description: Shutdown vms
### END INIT INFO
```

The script shutdown guest vms when host is shutdown. It runs fine for shutdown (0) and reboot (6).

The problem is, how do I make it run for user logout (when user log out, it should shutdown the vms)?

The rc2.d directory shows:
K01shutdownvms which is the first script to run.

Is it possible to run the script on logout without using gdm PostSession/rc.local/bash.logout etc?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking if Debian's [upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) can do it. No it can't. You have to use the mechanisms that you've mentioned.

But please re-consider the whole thing, because it is extremely rare practice to shutdown a system service  (i.e. possibly used by multiple users) on one user's logout.